# choosing a portable sound recorder and microphone

Tags: audio-recording, microphone

I am a musician and I want to record pub sessions etc. I am looking at voice recorders on eBay but it appears that all the ones with decent recording quality are very expensive (£100+) and to justify the price they have dozens of features and buttons that I don't want.

I figure it would be more economical to get a simple, cheap voice recorder (the only buttons I want are *record* and *stop*!) with a microphone socket, and get a separate microphone.

I don't want a big microphone, but a lapel-size thing. Still, I'm hoping to pick up sounds from ten metres away. I don't know how to choose a microphone, all the reviews seem to be for large studio mics, or pickups with limited spatial range.

Can anyone please reccommend me a microphone and/or a good basic portable sound recorder?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

My personal favorite is the [Zoom H4](http://www.zoom.co.jp/english/products/h4/). These are out of production, but if you can get a second hand one go for it. The quality is super IMO and you can record up to 24-bit at 96 kHz.

It has a simple record/stop button. It's XY-configured stereo mic setup creates a wide stereo field. At its bottom you can connect one or two either XLR or phono-jack based microphone(s) (it even has phantom power if you need to used condensed mics).

If still out of price range you can check out the [H1 series](http://www.zoom.co.jp/products/h1/) from the same manufacturer.

Hope this helps.